# Portable method to download files within R script?

Tags: r

I currently use `download.file` function to download file, I run my scripts in Linux and so I use this command:

```
download.file(url="https://example.com/zipfile.zip", destfile= "zipfile.zip", method="wget")
```

This comand does not work in Windows because `wget` is not there by default. If I use `method=auto` I get this error, which means download.file does not support `https` protocol.

```
Error in download.file(url="https://example.com/zipfile.zip", destfile= "zipfile.zip", method="auto") : unsupported URL scheme
```

How do I make this file download part works on all major OSes: Windows, Linux, Mac?

From the accepted answer, I looked at the documentation of `RCurl` and followed this example:

```
  u = "http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/data.gz"

if(url.exists(u)) {

  content = getBinaryURL(u)

  if(require(Rcompression)) {
    x = gunzip(content)
    read.csv(textConnection(x))
  } else {
     tmp = tempfile()
     write(content, file = tmp)
     read.csv(gzfile(tmp))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 Method curl or libcurl:

```
# try capabilities see if it is supported on your build.
capabilities("libcurl")
download.file(url="https://example.com/zipfile.zip", destfile= "zipfile.zip", method="libcurl")
```

## 2 Maybe Try [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/RCurl.pdf) package

```
library(RCurl)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the RCurl package. It supports multiple protocols. Just one drawback that I have to make sure it is installed before executing it. Anyway, I accept your answer.